# Double Opt-in SOAP API

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, soap

What SubscriberStatus i must define a list when you add a subscriber to the list and want the double opt-in work?

Where is my code of what am i doing:

```
        Subscriber sub = Subscriber.Factory.newInstance();
        sub.setEmailAddress(email);
        //This line is needed if SubscriberKey functionality is enabled in your account
        sub.setSubscriberKey(email);

        //Declare the list we want to add them to
        SubscriberList list = SubscriberList.Factory.newInstance();
        list.setID(listId);
        list.setStatus(SubscriberStatus.ACTIVE);
```